# how to store data to gridview paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying data from database to table with the help gridview  it is working fine and i am using paging in gridview for user convenient. When user click on next page controller going to server again and again for each page. I dont want that type performance but i need when user load the page controller only once should go to the server and come back with data, store the data in gridview paging is that possible? please help me. If you want i will share code...... or is any other solution is there please let me know......

Comment: please attach the code

Comment: Once you get the data back from the database and if you store the records in a static datatable once the Select returns data, you do not need to make any round trips in regards to Paging.. this is actually very easy to fix perhaps you have some inefficiency's happening in your code.. please show your current code by editing your original question and posting the code there..

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET cache to temporarily store your results.  On postback, pull out of the cache instead of going all the way back to the database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx